# BlazeDS on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, blazeds

Is there a way to use BlazeDS on a Glassfish server?  If so how?

Comment: You may find this moved over to Serverfault...

Answer (score 2):

The BlazeDS installation instructions [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Installation+Guide) cover running BlazeDS under J2EE app servers (of which Glassfish is one).