# Is there support for Glassfish in BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, glassfish, blazeds

#### Duplicate

> [BlazeDS on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365026/blazeds-on-glassfish)

I have a question about BlazeDS and Glassfish.

Is it true that there is no support for Blaze in GlassFish??

The following blog [has a "hack" solution](http://anachronymous.com/2009/01/flex-blazeds-and-glassfish-part-2.html), but I can't find an 'official' solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is support for Blaze in Glassfish, and all J2EE containers.  The BlazeDS installation instructions [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Installation+Guide) cover running BlazeDS  (of which Glassfish is one).

Answer (score 1):

There was no commercial support from Adobe if you decided to use Glassfish and BlazeDS, however you can use it if you want - I mean it works. BlazeDS is lightweight enough, it should work well with any J2EE container. And btw, Adobe decided to stop offering subscription support for BlazeDS.